# Is a quotient vector space of dimension 1 the kernel of a functional?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$F$ is a field and $H$ is a subspace of the vector space $F^n$ of codimension 1. Then is the quotient space $F^n/H$ the kernel of a linear functional?

Comment: Have you tried to prove this? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: You probably have the question wrong, as $F^n/H$ is not even a subspace of $F^n$, where I would assume we define the kernel.

Comment: I assume you want to know whether H is the kernel of a linear functional. Hint: look at the quotient map, and identify the quotient with F.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define the map $f\colon F^n/H\to F$ by $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in F^n/H$. Almost by definition $\ker f= F^n/H$ as required.